# Shift text upwards in graphics so characters with descenders clear horizontal lines

Tags: fonts

Is there an option to align Text to automatically adjust for font descent?

In the attached graphic, strings that contain "g"  are visibly shifted upward, even though all strings are uniformly rendered by:

```
Text[Style[name, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
  FontSize -> 12], {(b + 20), y}, {-1, -0.85}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to align strings vertically by the font's baseline? You can also see this issue in a simpler example:

```
  Graphics[
     {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
      Text["g", {1/4, 0.01}],
      Text["h", {3/4, 0.01}]},
     PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}
     ]
```

which somehow doesn't replicate the issue (M9/OSX10.8)

[image]

Comment: How do you want it adjusted? And with respect to what? Also, I think you need to post more code. Context is important here. An example pruned down to two or three time lines will do.

Comment: @m_goldberg, edited accordingly

Comment: Your sample code doesn't reproduce your problem on my system. Both h and g are aligned to same baseline, with the descender of the g going below the line. Might be good to discuss this in chat. I'll open a chat room.

Comment: Where is the link to the chat please?

Comment: Click on the stack exchange logo on the site toolbar. On the drop down menu, click on "chat"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the y-shift introduced by the 3rd argument to `Text`, which is in a different coordinate system from the main plot. You need to get rid of the y-shift in the 3rd argument and do the shift in the 2nd argument.

Change

```
Text[Style[name, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 12], {(b + 20), y}, {-1, -0.85}]
```

to

```
Text[Style[name, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 12], {(b + 20), y + .35}, {-1, 0}]
```

and see if that works.

[image: time-lines]

You may have to tweak the 0.35 shift. I set that by trial-and-error.

#### Edit

OP's code as modified by me.

```
q = 
  {"roentgen" -> {1845, 1923}, "lorentz" -> {1853, 1928}, 
   "zeeman" -> {1865, 1943}, "van der waals" -> {1837, 1923}, 
   "starck" -> {1874, 1957}, "einstein" -> {1879, 1955}, 
   "bohr" -> {1885, 1962}, "ehrenfest" -> {1880, 1933}, 
   "born" -> {1882, 1970}, "schroedinger" -> {1887, 1961}, 
   "pauli" -> {1900, 1958}, "de broglie" -> {1892, 1987}, 
   "heisenberg" -> {1901, 1976}, "dirac" -> {1902, 1984}, 
   "jordan" -> {1902, 1980}, "planck" -> {1858, 1947}, 
   "sommerfeld" -> {1868, 1951}, "brillouin" -> {1889, 1969}};

Module[{color1 = Darker @ Darker @ Blue}, 
  Graphics[({#1, #2[[1]]} & ~MapIndexed~
    SortBy[q, #[[2, 1]]&]) /. {name_ -> {b_, d_}, y_} :> {color1, 
    Text[Style[name, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 12], 
      {(b + 20), y + .35}, {-1, 0}], 
    Thickness[0.0005], Line[{{b, y}, {d, y}}], PointSize[0.005], 
    Point[{b, y}], Point[{d, y}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 1000, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[{Gray, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
    Frame -> {Automatic, None, None, None}]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was simple after all

Comment: +1, but where is the code to generate this graphic?  Is it from the documentation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Edited answer to add code. It was posted in the chat room where we discussed this question. Sorry I didn't think to show it.